# RegEx select url and strip a part

Tags: regex, expression

I have this:

```
<li><a href="/page.asp?dac=all&amp;num=266">Company Name</a></li>
```

Using the following RegEx I could grab the url part:

```
(?<=<li><a href=").*num=.*(?=">)
```

I want to get the url without `"amp;"` section.
So the result would be like:

```
/page.asp?dac=all&num=266
```

How should I do that?

Comment: `(?<=<li><a href=").*?(?=&amp)`

Comment: I might have misunderstood - do you want the `num` part?

Comment: The whole link WITHOUT &amp;

Comment: Then you need som kind of code. What environment are we talking about? Language, Editor... (You'll have to use capture groups)

Comment: I using a Bot maker software. ZennoPoster, if it's not against rules here.

Comment: I guess what you really want to do is decode the string. I.e. Convert the `&amp;` entity to `&`.

Comment: Can ZennoPoster use capture groups in the regex? If so, you could use that and output \1 and \2. For example :  
          <li><a href="(.*)amp;(num=.*)">

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using regex replace.

For C# it can look like the following:

```
var input = "<li><a href="/page.asp?dac=all&amp;num=266">Company Name</a></li>";
var pattern = ".*<a href="(?<before>.*)&amp;(?<after>.*)">.*";
var replace = "${before}&${after}";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is just:

`s/(?<=<li><a href=".*)(?:amp;)(.*)/$1$2/`

then `<li><a href="/page.asp?dac=all&amp;num=266">Company Name</a></li>`

becomes `<li><a href="/page.asp?dac=all&num=266">Company Name</a></li>`